# How to change cached Cloudflare cookie?

Tags: caching, cookies, microsoft-edge, cloudflare

Recently we had issues with Cloudflare caching our web shop, so disabled it. But its cookie `__cfduid` was left cached in clients or providers computers.
This particular cookie is making issues in Edge browser (a shopping cart is deleted on any new page load). The cookie has `HttpOnly Yes`, so can't just be changed with PHP script.
It will expire in one year, but meantime...

Do you know how can I change it (send a new one `__cfduid` to the client computer with the date expired or else)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior doesn't sound typical.  We have a lot of customers with eCommerce sites and this doesn't seem to be an issue.  You may want to submit a ticket at [support.cloudflare.com](http://support.cloudflare.com) or ask this question at [community.cloudflare.com](http://community.cloudflare.com).